# App launched from phone doesn't behave as from Android Studio via USB

Tags: android-studio

App launched from phone doesn't behave as from android studio

Function loadSteps works fine on phone when app is run from android studio via USB, but not when launched from the icon on the phone.

```
private fun loadSteps() {

val file = File(filesDir, "data.txt")


// Read data from the file

if (file.exists()) {

val input = FileInputStream(file)

val buffer = ByteArray(input.available())

input.read(buffer)

input.close()


// Convert the JSON string to a list of DataBlock

val json = String(buffer)

allSteps = DataBlock.fromJson(json) ?: mutableListOf()

}


val today = Calendar.getInstance().apply {

set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)

set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)

set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)

set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

}.time


if (allSteps.isEmpty()) {

// Add a new DataBlock with today's date and steps = 0

allSteps.add(DataBlock(today, 0))

} else {

val latestDate = allSteps.last().date

var latestCalendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply { time = latestDate }

val currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().apply {

set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)

set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)

set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)

set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

}


// Add new DataBlocks for missing dates between the latest date and today

while (latestCalendar.before(currentDate)) {

latestCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)

allSteps.add(DataBlock(latestCalendar.time, 0))

}

}



}
```

This part work ok

```
if (file.exists()) {

val input = FileInputStream(file)

val buffer = ByteArray(input.available())

input.read(buffer)

input.close()


// Convert the JSON string to a list of DataBlock

val json = String(buffer)

allSteps = DataBlock.fromJson(json) ?: mutableListOf()

}
```

but the rest of the code doesn't get executed. This is my first app and I ran into a wall.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for your reply!

Problem solved:

I have called this function within onCreate, so when app resumed or started it did not got called.